# How to select values that already exists in column

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select all rows by value that posted more than one time.

Table:

```
key  | value
------------
key1 | value
key2 | value
key2 | value
key3 | value
key3 | value
key4 | value
```

I need result like:

```
key2 | value
key3 | value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below should get you what you need.

```
select key
from table
group by key
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: There would have to be some sort of aggregation function to get meaningful 'value' results too. This is because you are trying to squeeze together a bunch of values from the 'value' column when you do the group by. Hope that makes sense! :)

Answer (score 3):

To find "duplicate" values of `key`, along with one of the values of `value`:

```
SELECT t.key
     , MAX(t.value)
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP BY t.key
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

To get `(key,value)` tuples that have "duplicates" in the table:

```
SELECT t.key
     , t.value
  FROM mytable t
 GROUP 
    BY t.key
     , t.value
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```